# python convert integer to bytes with bitwise operations

Tags: python

I have 2 inputs: i (the integer), length (how many bytes the integer should be encoded).

how can I convert integer to bytes only with bitwise operations.

```
def int_to_bytes(i, length):
  for _ in range(length):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Without libraries (as specified in the original post), use [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).

```
>>> (1234).to_bytes(16, "little")
b'\xd2\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

IOW, your function would be

```
def int_to_bytes(i, length):
    return i.to_bytes(length, "little")
```

(or `big`, if you want big-endian order).

With just bitwise operations,

```
def int_to_bytes(i, length):
    buf = bytearray(length)
    for j in range(length):
        buf[j] = i & 0xFF
        i >>= 8
    return bytes(buf)

print(int_to_bytes(1234, 4))
```

Comment: sorry no libraries. just bitwise operations

Comment: what if i want big endian?

Comment: You reverse the output.